# 'C' Program: multidimensional array issue

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Please help me figure this out, I have tested it and tested it and re-read and re-wrote for the past 11 hours and I give up. I found a working code that someone else wrote, but it still doesn't explain to me why his works and mine doesn't because the problem that I am having works on his but not on mine

Got it people, code edited for anyone who has had a similiar problem...
The original code that I had is here http://pastebin.com/h7fXHKzf
the problem I was having was that it kept hanging up on the if(board[x][y - 1] == '.') checks.

Spoke too soon....The program will sometimes crash...it's rare but has crashed 3x in a row before...most of the time when I run it everything works.

```
    // Chapter 8 Programming Project #9

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>

    #define SIZE 10
    #define PATH_SIZE ((int) (sizeof(brd_path)))
    #define ROW_SIZE ((int) (sizeof(board) / sizeof(board[0])))

    int main(void)
    {
        char board[SIZE][SIZE] = {};
        char brd_path[25] = {'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
                             'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O',
                             'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V',
                             'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
        // 0 = Up, 1 = Down, 2 = Left, 3 = Right
        bool path_dir_chk[4] = {false};
        bool blocked = false;
        unsigned short i, j, x = 0, y = 0;
        // Generate a random number
        srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
        int dir = rand() % 4;
        // Set all positions of board to '.'
        for (x = 0; x < ROW_SIZE; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < ROW_SIZE; y++)
                board[x][y] = '.';

        }
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        board[0][0] = 'A';
        // Generate the path
        while (blocked != true && i != PATH_SIZE) {
            for (i = 0; i < PATH_SIZE;) {
                // Reset path_dir_chk values if empty
                for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    if (board[x][y - 1] == '.')
                        path_dir_chk[0] = false;
                    if (board[x][y + 1] == '.')
                        path_dir_chk[1] = false;
                    if (board[x - 1][y] == '.')
                        path_dir_chk[2] = false;
                    if (board[x + 1][y] == '.') 
                        path_dir_chk[3] = false;
                }
                // Check the direction and replace that char
                switch (dir) {
                    case 0: if ((y - 1) >= 0 && board[x][y - 1] == '.') {
                        board[x][--y] = brd_path[i];
                        path_dir_chk[0] = true;
                        printf("I is now: %d\n", ++i);
                    } break;
                    case 1: if ((y + 1) >= 0 && board[x][y + 1] == '.') {
                        board[x][++y] = brd_path[i];
                        path_dir_chk[1] = true;
                        printf("I is now: %d\n", ++i);
                    } break;
                    case 2: if ((x - 1) >= 0 && board[x - 1][y] == '.') {
                        board[--x][y] = brd_path[i];
                        path_dir_chk[2] = true;
                        printf("I is now: %d\n", ++i);
                    } break;
                    case 3: if ((x + 1) >= 0 && board[x + 1][y] == '.') {
                        board[++x][y] = brd_path[i];
                        path_dir_chk[3] = true;
                        printf("I is now: %d\n", ++i);
                    } break;
                }
            // if all path's are true exit
            if (path_dir_chk[0] == true &&
                path_dir_chk[1] == true &&
                path_dir_chk[2] == true &&
                path_dir_chk[3] == true)
                blocked = true;
            // Reset the random direction
            dir = rand() % 4;
            }
        }
        // Print the board
        for (x = 0; x < ROW_SIZE; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < ROW_SIZE; y++)
                printf("%c ", board[x][y]);
            printf("\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

OK I have made changes to reflect what I have so far, no it is printing 'I is now:' numbers 1 - 25 and then it starts over but it stops on 12 the second time around and freezes into some kind of loop

Below is the working code I found online, you can compare the two and see the similarity's but the lines of code on his that are exactly like mine do not work on mine.....

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>

    #define ROWS 10
    #define COLS 10
    int main (void)
    {
        int i, j, k, direction;
        char board[ROWS][COLS];
        const char letters[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',
                                'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
                                'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R',
                                'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
                                'Y', 'Z'};

        srand ((unsigned) time(NULL));

        for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
          for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            board[i][j] = '.';

        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        k = 1;
        //set array[0][0] to first element
        board[i][j] = letters[0];
        while (k < 26) {
            direction = rand() % 4;

            if (board[i][j] == '.')
                board[i][j] = letters[k++];
            if ((board[i][j + 1] != '.' || j == ROWS - 1 )&&
                (board[i + 1][j] != '.' || i == COLS -1) &&
                (board[i - 1][j] != '.' || i == 0) &&
                (board[i][j - 1] != '.' || j == 0))
                break;
            switch (direction) {
              case 0: if (j < ROWS - 1 && board[i][j + 1] == '.'){  //move right
                      j++;
                      break;     }
              case 1: if (i < COLS -1 && board[i + 1][j] == '.') {  //move down
                      i++;
                      break; }
              case 2: if (i > 0 && board[i - 1][j] == '.'){  //move up
                      i--;
                      break;  }
              case 3: if (j > 0 && board[i][j - 1] == '.') { //move left
                      j--;
                      break; }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
          for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            printf ("%4c", board[i][j]);
          printf ("\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your indentation is misleading in that "`TestX`" block, you might need extra `{}`s.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, good point, but I fixed it and still nothing, screen is completely blank, and I'm stuck in a loop because i only iterates after a switch if statement has been completed.

Comment: no error, just blank screen

Comment: by the way in case you were wondering the case 0: through case 3: does work, its the if statements that correlate with the board[x][y - 1] == '.' or y+1 or x-1 or x+1 that aren't working, when it checks to see if that position is equal to '.' it thinks that it isn't I switched it from == to != and the tests started printing but it won't work if it doesn't know that a character exsists there

Comment: Add newline at the end of output strings in  each `printf` or `fflush(stdout);` after `printf`. Otherwise, the output is buffered and nothing is written.

Comment: `// 0 = Up, 1 = Down, 2 = Left, 3 = Right` Why a comment and not an enum for this? `enum { Up, Down, Left, Right};` ...

Comment: Oh well I haven't learned enum yet

Comment: And Marian I tried the fflush(stdout); like you said and it still wasn't printing anything I just get a blinking _ in the console window.

Comment: Please note that ISO C forbids empty initializer braces.

Comment: oh, I am using Code::Blocks 13.12 on window 8.1 and I have it set to use the c99 standard because that's what this book is based on

Comment: Ok in case people are still checking these up here, I did get it working printing I is now: 1 all the way through 12 and crashes....so apparently it ran off the board...I am going to try that now...Thanks everyone!

Comment: Please _do not_ edit your question to show the answer for future readers. How will they understand what was changed? Instead, keep the question as it is and post an _answer_ with the corrections in. Posting an answer to your own question is just fine.

Comment: why a seperate `brd_path[25]`? Just `i + 'B'` (or `i + 'A'`  for the below code) is enough, and it'll be faster than a table lookup

Comment: that's actually a pretty good idea, and sorry Lundin your right..I'm still a noob, I'll keep that in mind next time

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Pqvhrgzy go there to see what I got so far I did as you said Luu Vinh Phuc, and I eliminated nearly 35-40 lines of useless code. the problem is that it still hangs randomly, sometimes it will hang with a flickering '_' and others it will work just fine

Comment: Ok so here is the code after the last referal for < ROW_SIZE --> http://pastebin.com/j7cZ2bwM and it's still hanging randomly with the flickering underscore

Comment: First, a minor nitpick, the code has a `for` loop nested in a `while` loop. That outer `while` loop serves no purpose and can be removed.  Next, a little encouragement, you've come a long way, the code is looking good, and all of the range checking is solid.  The problem now is that the code can get into a situation where there are no valid moves left, so you need to detect that case and break out of the loop. I'm gonna get some sleep, you should too :)

Comment: Thanks :) I'll make sure to take that un-needed while loop out and fix the latter, thanks again for all the help

Comment: hey user3386109 here is the new code http://pastebin.com/nwnZP1ET It seems to work quite well, but something is still amidst it hangs once about every 12th time I run the program? I can't figure out what I missed

Comment: Wow, you really cleaned it up, nice!  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks user3386109 your input was invaluable as was the rest of y'alls help I appreciate it, the working code is below :)

```
    // Chapter 8 Programming Project #9

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>

    #define SIZE 10
    #define PATH_SIZE 25
    #define ROW_SIZE ((int) (sizeof(board) / sizeof(board[0])))

    int main(void)
    {
        char board[SIZE][SIZE];
        // 0 = Up, 1 = Down, 2 = Left, 3 = Right
        unsigned short i = 0, x, y;
        // Generate a random number
        srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
        int dir = rand() % 4;
        // Set all positions of board to '.'
        for (x = 0; x < ROW_SIZE; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < ROW_SIZE; y++)
                board[x][y] = '.';
        }
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        board[0][0] = 'A';
        // Generate the path
        for (i = 0; i < PATH_SIZE;) {
                // Check that the last character has not been cornered
            if ((board[x][y - 1] != '.' || y - 1 < 0) &&
                (board[x][y + 1] != '.' || y + 1 > ROW_SIZE) &&
                (board[x - 1][y] != '.' || x - 1 < 0) &&
                (board[x + 1][y] != '.' || x + 1 > ROW_SIZE))
                break;
            // Check the direction and replace that char
            switch (dir) {
                case 0: if ((y - 1) >= 0
                            && board[x][y - 1] == '.') {
                            board[x][--y] = i + 'B';
                            ++i;
                        } break;
                case 1: if ((y + 1) < ROW_SIZE
                            && board[x][y + 1] == '.') {
                            board[x][++y] = i + 'B';
                            ++i;
                        } break;
                case 2: if ((x - 1) >= 0
                            && board[x - 1][y] == '.') {
                            board[--x][y] = i + 'B';
                            ++i;
                        } break;
                case 3: if ((x + 1) < ROW_SIZE
                            && board[x + 1][y] == '.') {
                            board[++x][y] = i + 'B';
                            ++i;
                        } break;
                default: if (board[x][y] == '.')
                             board[x][y] = i + 'B';
                             break;
            }
        // Reset the random directions
        dir = rand() % 4;
        }
        // Print the board
        for (x = 0; x < ROW_SIZE; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < ROW_SIZE; y++)
                printf("%4c ", board[x][y]);
            printf("\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting x and y back to 0 after this code

```
for (x = 0; x < ROW_SIZE; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < ROW_SIZE; y++)
            board[x][y] = '.';
    }
```

Thus x and y will start at 10.  Also you aren't range checking x and y, which means that x and y might wander off the board.

This code

```
    if ((board[x][y - 1] != '.' || y - 1 < 0) &&
        (board[x][y + 1] != '.' || y + 1 > ROW_SIZE) &&
        (board[x - 1][y] != '.' || x - 1 < 0) &&
        (board[x + 1][y] != '.' || x + 1 > ROW_SIZE))
```

should be this

```
    if ((y - 1 <  0        || board[x][y - 1] != '.') &&
        (y + 1 >= ROW_SIZE || board[x][y + 1] != '.') &&
        (x - 1 <  0        || board[x - 1][y] != '.') &&
        (x + 1 >= ROW_SIZE || board[x + 1][y] != '.'))
```

There are two subtle differences.

First y+1 and x+1 are not allowed to be equal to ROW_SIZE, since ROW_SIZE is 10, but the valid array indices are 0 to 9.

Second, order is important. When evaluating a logical OR, the left side is evaluated first, and if it's true, then the right side is **not** evaluated.  This is important, since on some machines, even reading outside of the array bounds will cause a crash.

Comment: I edited the source above to reflect the new changes...I placed x = 0; and y = 0; right below that and it still is doing the same thing

Comment: you put them inside the loop :D

Comment: sorry, my head is so fried from sitting here for going on 12 hours now trying to figure this out

Comment: seemed to work!!! it printed out all the tests and a I is now: 1 and then about a dozen more tests and crashed :(

Comment: Yup, either x or y wandered off the board.  You can see in the other person's code that some checking is done to see if `i` or `j` are at the edge of the board.  However, that code is still not quite right.  You need to make sure that you never access the board array with x,y values <0 or >=ROWSIZE

Comment: Ok I fixed that and it ran through I is now: 1-25 twice and stopped at 12 the third time and got stuck in a loop, I think I may be able to figure this one out i'm gonna check it out...

Comment: The program works now but it randomly hangs with a blank console, I can then exit out and go back in and it will work

Comment: Hmm, I see two places that need improvement.  After this comment `// Reset path_dir_chk values if empty` the values of x and y in the for loop need to be checked.  Then in case 1: and case 3: the code checks >= 0, but it needs to check the upper bound, which would be < ROW_SIZE

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Pqvhrgzy go there to see what I got so far I did as you said Luu Vinh Phuc, and I eliminated nearly 35-40 lines of useless code. the problem is that it still hangs randomly, sometimes it will hang with a flickering '_' and others it will work just fine

Comment: oh thanks user3386109 I think that may be the reason for the random crashing

Comment: Ok so here is the code after the last referal for < ROW_SIZE --> http://pastebin.com/j7cZ2bwM and it's still hanging randomly with the flickering underscore

Comment: Thanks again I finally got it working properly, not too long before I went too bed...I posted the working code at the bottom and accepted your response as the answer as it was very helpful, believe it or not I actually ran the program 35-40 times over and over I lost count but I think I stopped at 40 and it never crashed :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (x = 0; x < ROW_SIZE; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < ROW_SIZE; y++)
                board[x][y] = '.';
        }
```

After the initialization you are not resetting the value of x and y. While value of X= ROW_SIZE, you are trying to access board[x + 1][y] and board[x][y + 1].

```
x = 0;
y = 0;
```